# Проблема с загрузкой дампа базы PostgreSQL. (Ansible)

Tags: postgresql, ansible, dump

Дело такое: Есть проект на django под пользователем
Задача состоит в том, чтобы создать нового пользователя и скопировать этот проект для него.
Все бы ничего, но появилась проблема с импортом базы.
Делаю следующие шаги:

1. создаю новый проект для нового пользователя и все настраиваю (полностью идентичный проект как у старого пользователя)

2 далее удаляю базу у нового пользователя и создаю новую

```
 - name: Remove PostgreSQL db
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_db:
    name: "{{ username }}"
    state: absent
  when: dbtype == "pg"

- name: Create db PostgreSQL
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_db:
    name: "{{ dbname }}"
    encoding: UTF-8
    template: template0
    state: present
  when: dbtype == "pg"
```

3 Делаю дамп базы старого пользователя

```
- name: Dump Databases PostgreSQL
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_db :
    name:  "{{ copy_dbname }}"
    state:  dump
    target: "/tmp/{{ copy_dbname }}.sql"
  when: dbtype == "pg"
```

4 Импортирую базу

```
- name: Import databases PostgreSQL
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  shell: "psql {{ dbname }} < /tmp/{{ copy_dbname }}.sql"
  when: dbtype == "pg"
```

Все бы ничего, но при открытии проекта в браузере выплевывает ошибку:

> Internal Server Error

Помогите пожалуйста. Думаю дело именно в базе, т.к. до импорта базы пустой проект  работает...

Comment: В вопросе слишком много посторонних бесполезных сущностей. Проверьте логи своего приложения, веб-сервера, сделайте дамп базы вручную и выбросите из вопроса всё лишнее. Если после этого в вопросе вообще хоть что-то останется. В частности, я уверен что ansible в вопросе лишний и никак не связан с проблемой.

Comment: Проблема оказалась в том, что база не удаляется из за активных подключений. Сейчас разбираюсь с этой проблемой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим путем. Так как база не удалялась из за активных подключений к ней - пришлось дописать скрипт который удалял эти подключения:

```
- name: Removing connections to the database
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  shell: |
    psql;
    echo try method for 9.2 and above...
    echo "SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname='{{ dbname }}' AND pid<>pg_backend_pid();" | psql {{ username }}
    echo try method for 9.1 and below...
    echo "SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.procpid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname='{{ dbname }}' AND procpid<>pg_backend_pid();" | psql {{ username }}
  when: dbtype == "pg"
```

Так ошибка была в том, что импорт базы производился под пользователем postgres, из этого следовало что все таблицы остались под правами старого пользователя. То есть импорт базы надо было делать под новым пользователем:

```
- name: Import databases PostgreSQL
  become: yes
  become_user: {{ username }}
  shell: "psql {{ dbname }} < /tmp/{{ copy_dbname }}.sql"
  when: dbtype == "pg"
```